# Why did this Not an Answer flag get declined when it was just a copy paste of another answer with only a minor change to the code

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, specific-answer

I flagged the following as Not an Answer: [Execute multiple async actions in the gulp task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53659909/execute-multiple-async-actions-in-the-gulp-task/71715714#71715714)

This is just a copy/paste of another answer (with no attribution!), with 1 line trivially changed to fix a typo. (without any explanation what exactly changed)

According to the description of the Not an Answer flag, it should be used if a answer should be an comment, which is the place to point out if there is a mistake in another answer.

Yet a moderator declined this flag, so where am I wrong in the logic that this should be a comment *or* edit suggestion to the other answer?

Comment: _"This is just a copy/paste of another **answer**"_ So it's plagiarism, and not NAA. Plagiarism requires a custom flag.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Why did this Not an Answer flag get declined when it was just a copy paste of another answer with only a minor change to the code

Because detecting that requires reading all of the other answers to the question and comparing them to the flagged one, which is not something that moderators do when processing "not an answer" flags.

If there is some issue with the answer that is not obvious from reading the answer itself in isolation, then you should raise a custom flag and explain the problem.

Related Reading: [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552)

Comment: (+ The User only has 1-Rep, so they wouldn't have been able to post a Comment...)

Comment: The user's reputation is completely irrelevant to the usage or applicability of a "not an answer" flag.